# How to apply wildcard to column list in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to know How to use wildcard in `select`

For example, I would like to extract `columns` which contains for example `test`.

How can I extract this?

```
Select 
From T2
```

My desired result is like this

```
test1 test2 test3
1     2     3
4     5     6
```

Thanks

Comment: That is not possible. SQL does not work liks that. The columns need to be predefined.

Comment: SQL accepts wildcards for string colums (e.g. `select * from myTable where myString like 'test%`.  But you can't do that for column *names*...

Comment: And if you need such a feature then your table design is probably very wrong

Comment: You can use the dynamic query for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the dynamic query as follows:

```
SQL> var lv_cur refcursor;
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2      LV_COLS          VARCHAR2(32000);
  3      LV_TABLE_NAME    VARCHAR2(128) := 'STUDENTS';
  4      LV_SCHEMA_NAME   VARCHAR2(128) := 'TEJASH';
  5      LV_COLUMN_STARTWITH VARCHAR2(10) := 'S';
  6      --LV_CUR           SYS_REFCURSOR;
  7  BEGIN
  8      SELECT
  9          LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP(
 10              ORDER BY
 11                  COLUMN_ID
 12          )
 13      INTO LV_COLS
 14      FROM
 15          ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
 16      WHERE
 17          TABLE_NAME = LV_TABLE_NAME
 18          AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE  LV_COLUMN_STARTWITH || '%'
 19          AND OWNER = LV_SCHEMA_NAME;
 20
 21      IF LV_COLS IS NOT NULL THEN
 22          OPEN :LV_CUR FOR 'SELECT '
 23                          || LV_COLS
 24                          || ' FROM '
 25                          || LV_SCHEMA_NAME
 26                          || '.'
 27                          || LV_TABLE_NAME;
 28
 29      ELSE
 30          OPEN :LV_CUR FOR 'SELECT ''NO DATA'' FROM DUAL';
 31      END IF;
 32  END;
 33  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> PRINT LV_cUR;

      S_ID S_NAME     S_ADDRESS     S_LEVEL S_RECORDS_POINTS    S_MAJOR    S_CLASS
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------- ---------- ----------
         1 TEJASH     A2                  1           15.972          1          1

SQL>
```

I have used this block to fetch the data of the column having S as the starting character in the `STUDENTS` table(`TEJASH` schema). If there is no column satisfying the condition then `NO DATA` will be displayed.

Comment: CAVEAT: This is completely Oracle-specific.  "SQL" per se does not allow this.  As Juergen D said: "if you need such a feature then your table design is probably very wrong..."

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

SQL Server

```
select * 
from information_schema.columns 
where column_name like 'test%' 
order by 
    table_name
```

Oracle

```
select 
     table_name, 
     column_name 
from all_tab_columns 
where column_name like 'test%'
and owner in ('your_schema_name')
```